# How to define a newcommand for this type of indexing?

Tags: macros, indexing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\key}[1]{ #1 \index{#1} }

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
This shows \key{1.1},\key{1.2},\key{1.3},\key{1.4},\key{2}.
% \key{1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2}

\cleardoublepage
This shows \key{1.1},\key{1.2},\key{2.3},\key{1.4},\key{2}.
% \key{1.1,1.2,2.3,1.4,2}

\cleardoublepage
This shows \key{1.1},\key{3.2},\key{5.3},\key{A},\key{C}.
\cleardoublepage
This shows \key{1.1},\key{E},\key{A},\key{D},\key{3.2}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Instead of using seperate `\key{}`s, is there a way to use ONE `\key{}`, but still being able to use it for indexing?

For example:

Thanks!

Comment: Is this just some example or why do you want to index `1.1` etc? Do you want to index the last counter (value) that was stepped? I don't understand this question so far. If you use the same `\key` over and over again, which information should go to `\index`? And consider the `\index{foo!bar}` subentries. Or do you want to use a CSV-list?

Comment: the way `\key` is defined here will result in raggedy spacing in the output, since the spaces (separated by `\index{...}`) are no longer consecutive, and thus not compressed by tex..also, it's possible that the page number assigned to the index term may be one greater than appropriate, in the case where the typeset `#1` finishes off the last line of a page, forcing the `\index` to go to the next page.

Comment: Defining a macro that uses a comma-seperated list could be one way. Implementation of such a thing I leave to others.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is exactly what I want to index and is not an example. It's part of a big problem I hope to achieve. So for example, if I use `\key{1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4}`, I want this to be the same as `\key{1.1},\key{1.2},\key{1.3},\key{1.4}`. There is no need for subentries.

Comment: @barbarabeeton For my actual problem, I will NOT be considering page numbers. Instead, I would want to use, say for example, the section number like a reference.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Here is the full problem if interested. Thanks. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253780/indexing-and-bookmarking-and-compiling-final-pdf-making-a-template

Comment: @ChenStatsYu -- it would be helpful if you added into your question an example of what you would like an index entry to look like.  from the present description, i was picturing something like "2.1, 37" or "A, 15:, and i'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry if that was not quite clear. I made a full description of the problem here. And I am not sure if latex (tex) can do this. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253780/indexing-and-bookmarking-and-compiling-final-pdf-making-a-template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a quick-and-dirty way which both displays the index key and adds it to the Index, using `\forcsvlist` command for the first arg of `\key` command, which is a CSV - list

Longer keys with white space must be put in `{...}`, as well as keys which have a `,` inside.

The `\dispkey` is this CVS-list processing (helper) macro.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\dispkey}[1]{%
#1 \index{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\key}[1]{%
  \forcsvlist{dispkey}{#1}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]

\key{This,that,{and this one}}
\blindtext[2]
\key{1.1,1.2,1.3}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose you're being faithful to the code of the question, but I usually find it better to do something like `\newcommand{\dispkey}[1]{\index{#1}#1}`.  At at least you don't want to put an explicit space between `#1` and `\index{#1}`.

Comment: @jon: Keeping the original style was my only intention to use it the `#1 \index{#1}` way. I wouldn't use the whole stuff this way however. ;-) Thanks for your comment

Comment: @jon The "explicit space" was there because it reads more natural to me, so I would not forget to put an extra or miss any delimiters. Is there any danger of this "explicit space"?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu -- Yes there is: try putting a punctuation mark after `\key{<whatever>}`.  @Christian -- Indeed. It was, I suppose, more of a general warning. (I did +1 already.)

Comment: @Jon: No worries ;-)

Comment: I am feeling the presence of `expl3` - force. Some guy will add a longer version with `expl3` soon ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Shorter, you mean. `;-)`

Comment: Why do you expand `#1` in the definition of `\key`? `\newcommand{\key}[1]{\forcsvlist{\dispkey}{#1}}` will work in your example.

Comment: Also: there are no commas between the (printed) keys anymore (the question has them...)

Comment: @clemens: Yes, it works -- I had something more complicated in my mind. Thanks for notifying. As for the commas --> I'll think about it

Answer (score 6):

A very short implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\key}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    ##1\index{##1}~
   }
   \unskip
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\key{This,that,{and this one}}

\key{1.1,1.2,1.3}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to preserve the commas between the keys in the text, then a slightly more complex approach is needed. We store the keys in a sequence, then extract the first item to be treated specially (no comma before it) and then map the remaining items prefixing them with a comma-space. The mapping will result in nothing if there was just one item.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\key}{m}
 {
  \chen_key:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_chen_keys_seq
\tl_new:N \l_chen_first_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \chen_key:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_chen_keys_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_chen_keys_seq \l_chen_first_tl
  \chen_print_and_index:Vn \l_chen_first_tl {}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_chen_keys_seq
   {
    \chen_print_and_index:nn { ##1 } { ,~ }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chen_print_and_index:nn #1 #2
 {
  #2 #1 \index{#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chen_print_and_index:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\key{This,that,{and this one}}

\key{1.1,1.2,1.3}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here's the first page:

[image]

Comment: Like @Christian's answer this loses the commas between the keys...

Comment: Does `\unskip` undo the horizontal space?

Comment: The version which preserves the commas is not, however, 'shorter', is it?!

Comment: @cfr It's not really much longer. It automatically trims spaces around entries; it is easy to set up a different delimiter; the `\index` command is fed with the actual entry and not with `\next`; there is no juggling in the meaning of `\my@join` (there even is no similar object). I could continue. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I was referring to your claim that it was shorter than Christian Hupfer's solution. Mine is longer. (Also, I'm only teasing: not only did I vote your answer up because it is excellent. I also voted your comment saying it would be shorter up because I liked it.) Still like to know about `\unskip`, though. (I thought this had to do with vertical space.)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with no extra packages and no expl3 syntax. (I'm not saying these are advantages. But they are features of my answer, whether good or bad.)

This solution is short, inserts a comma and a space between consecutive keys, and does not insert such things before the first or after the last key in the list. If the list consists of a single key, just the key is printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\key[1]{%
  \def\my@keys{#1}%
  \let\my@join\relax
  \@for \xx:=\my@keys \do {%
    \index{\xx}\my@join\xx\gdef\my@join{, }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some keys: \key{1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2} are shown here.

\key{1.1,1.2,2.3,1.4,2} are some more keys.

\key{1.1}, which is a nice key, comes before the extremely horrid key \key{3.2}.

Keys \key{5.3,A} and \key{C} are other keys.

Keys \key{1.1,E,A,D,3.2} show that something.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: simple key management]

[image: indexed keys]